# Make child element unaffected by rotation of parent element

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform

I have two div elements: one parent element, which is rotated, and one child element that I need to be unaffected by the rotation of the parent element.

To achieve this, I have attempted to rotate the child element in the opposite direction of the parent element. This works in some cases. For instance, if I rotate the elements like this ...

```
.parent {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.child {
 transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

... the child element will appear straight and undistorted. But if I rotate them with rotate**X** ...

```
.parent {
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
}

.child {
 transform: rotateX(-30deg);
}
```

... the child element still looks rather distorted.

The actual code uses both rotateX and rotateZ in order to make the parent element appear isometric. It currently looks like this:

```css
.happy_parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.happy_child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.sad_parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotateX(-60deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.sad_child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="happy_parent">
  <div class="happy_child"></div>
</div>

<div class="sad_parent">
  <div class="sad_child"></div>
</div>
```

Notice that the upper divs are both rendered correctly, but the lower child-div is still distorted.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are rotating in 3D direction . So now it will not just work by rotating in -ve direction

Comment: You have to reverse the order of `rotation` along with `-ve` `deg` . Like parent you `rotate` `X` first than `Z` now in child you have to first `rotate` `Z` than `X` . You can try to remove `transform-style: preserve-3d` and see the effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have the `innerElement` (`childElement`) to remain in initial state when rotated in 3D by rotating back in `-ve` `deg`.

It will work when rotation takes place in 2D .

But you can give a try to `transform-style: preserve-3d` to see the shapes in `3D` effect when rotated with `Z` coordinate also and preserve the shape instead of just showing in `2D` .

**You have to reverse the order of rotation too in 3D rotation**

> You can try to remove the `transform-style: preserve-3d` and see the effect

```css
.happy_parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.happy_child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);

}

.sad_parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotateX(-60deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.sad_child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg) rotateX(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="happy_parent">
  <div class="happy_child"></div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>

<div class="sad_parent">
  <div class="sad_child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Reversing the order of the transformations helped me achieve what i wanted.

Comment: Welcome , happy to help @Candleout . By the way how you managed as some of the parts are cut out